# Multiple UISwitches IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have 3 switches on my view controller. 
If the user changes any of these then the 3 settings need to be persisted to a db.

so

```
switch a = 1, switch b = 0 and switch c = 1
```

persist to db

```
switch a = 0, switch b = 1  and switch c = 1
```

perssit to db

```
switch a = 0, switch b = 0 and switch c = 0
```

persist to db
etc

I can trigger one fine with a event but when i try and compare the other ones when the event triggers on one switch i get loads of errors.

*I am using an If command and switch.on.*

So how can i trap an event when three switches are being amended.

thanks

UPDATE :::

I have done this code : and when i press the button i get the error

```
    [self.Switch1 addTarget:self action:@selector(flipswitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.NSwitch2 addTarget:self action:@selector(flipswitch:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.Switch3 addTarget:self action:@selector(flipswitch:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}


- (IBAction) flipSwitch: (UISwitch *) sender
{

}
```

and when i change a switch i get

2014-03-05 18:11:44.775 OutTonight[4788:60b] `-[SettingsViewController flipswitch:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15ec9fd0
2014-03-05 18:11:44.777 OutTonight[4788:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SettingsViewController flipswitch:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15ec9fd0'`

All I am trying to do is compare 3 switches and then just persist to the database.

Comment: If you need help with your code, post the code causing the issues. Explain what the problems are and what the errors are.

Comment: Why do you use DB? You can easily attach value of switcher to NSUSerDefaults.

Comment: Method name is `flipSwitch` and gave selector as `flipswitch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time make sure to display what errors you receive, so we can help you more specifically.

**To solve your problem, you need to follow those steps.**

1. Create three `IBOutlet`'s in your view controller, one for each switch, if you are using the Storyboard/Interface Builder. If you created them in code, create three instance variables.
2. Create a method such as:

   ```
   - (IBAction) flipSwitch: (UISwitch *) sender
   {
       ....
   }
   ```
3. Connect your 3 switches target action's with the following method:

   ```
   [switch addTarget: self action: @selector(flipSwitch:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
   ```
4. Implement your `flipSwitch:` method to access all 3 switches via instance variables you created in step 1 and save their status to the database. You can access the `on` property of each `UISwitch` instance to know which are on and off.

For more information on how to use `UISwitch` see the links below:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html
- [Creating a UISwitch Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025842/creating-a-uiswitch-programmatically)
- http://www.xprogress.com/post-30-uiswitch-tutorial-example-how-to-use-the-switch-in-xcode-for-iphone-sample-included/

*And many more examples can be found on Google.*

Comment: I have added a little bit of code to my question, thanks

Comment: In your code, you get the error, because your selector is for a lowercase method. Try the correct selector, the code is case-sensitive.